# Only last javascript file linked with script tag is working

Tags: javascript, html

I linked all the javascript files in the header.php at atime. I included header.php in all pages

When I link the javascript files like this

```
<script src='js/home.js'></script>
<script src='js/disc.js'></script>
<script src='js/que.js'></script>
```

only last file js/que.js is working.

Comment: Please specify clearly what you mean when you say "is working" ? And also what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Since obviously what you've shown **does** work and works on millions upon millions of web pages, you'll need to look more deeply into what isn't working and provide much more information in order for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the 'src' is referring to the correct file directory where the script is located. If you are using an IDE such as VS, then you may drag the file into the code and the IDE will automatically create the reference for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have problem with directory structure or you file name does not match with src attribute of script tag, there should not be any problem with. Please try to use **type="text/javascript"**  and make sure  your script tags are after header tag or just before `</body>` tag. Also keep sequence of files loading if any file depends on another file  variable or any function. If it still does not work use try to see if there is any error in your code in **console window**.

Answer (score 0):

I now I'm going to get voted down for this but oh well.  I don't have enough points to comment which is what I would do but..oh well.

Okay it depends on what the scripts are doing.  If you link the scripts in the head for you HTML page, and try a `var element = document.getElementById("theID");` this will return null due to the fact that the browser has yet to read the HTML and hasn't had a chance to create a DOM (Document Object Model) tree. For a problem like this check out

```
<script>
    function load() {
        console.log("load event detected!");
      }
    window.onload = load;
</script>
```

This will assign window to an event/callback that will be invoked after the page has had time to load. 
Look at where your JavaScript is used, and what it should be doing. Would those elements be rendered yet. Are you writing functions but not actually calling them (this happens A LOT)? It would be better if you described what the code was doing and your experience with HTML and JavaScript. Remember that the browser interprets the JavaScript as it encounters it, you can put script tags anywhere in your HTML file, not just in the head.  Also are the .js files in the same directory as the HTML file or are the two non working .js files in the same directory as `"js/que.js"`?  If not move them to the same file or use a relative or absolute path.